# Finite Borel measures on the cube are automatically Radon measures

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory

Let ${B}$ be a finite set, and let ${\mu_B}$ be a probability measure on ${[0,1]^B}$ (with the Borel ${\sigma}$-algebra). For any Borel set ${E}$ in ${[0,1]^B}$, establish the inner regularity property

$\displaystyle \mu_B(E) = \sup_{K \subset E, K \hbox{ compact}} \mu_B(K)$

and the outer regularity property

$\displaystyle \mu_B(E) = \inf_{U \supset E, U \hbox{ open}} \mu_B(U)$.

Hint: use the monotone class lemma.

**Question**: Let $\displaystyle \mathbf{G} = \{E\ \text{a Borel set of}\ [0,1]^B: \forall \epsilon > 0, \exists K \subset E \subset U, \text{K compact and U open}, \mu_B(U \setminus K) < \epsilon \}$. By the monotone class lemma, we conclude that $\sigma(\mathbf{G})$ is contained in the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of $[0,1]^B$. Now we want to show the other direction and conclude that the two algebras agree, but how is this attainable?

Comment: "...and the regularity properties clearly hold on these generators, aren’t they therefore hold on the entire algebra?" this non-trivial and precisely the point of the exercise.

Comment: @FZan: So the monotone class theorem would be used to show that the measure is regular on the generators?